# GD library for Docker image with php:7.1-fpm

Tags: php, docker

I have a Docker container

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD ["php-fpm"]

COPY nginx/www /var/www
COPY php/php /usr/local/etc/php
```

I tried to add some various code for installing GD library but all they didn't work.

I tried to add this

```
# GD LIB
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt zip pdo gd bcmath
```

I want to add GD library for PHP. Help me, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng-dev
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev libxpm-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-gd \
    --with-webp-dir \
    --with-jpeg-dir \
    --with-png-dir \
    --with-zlib-dir \
    --with-xpm-dir \
    --with-freetype-dir \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Try this code this working after build image run container and check container logs. show below result.

```
[15-May-2019 11:46:34] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[15-May-2019 11:46:34] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

Also, add nginx installation code.